# 恥知らず【はじしらず】 versus 厚顔無恥【こうがんむち】

Tags: word-choice, wago-and-kango, yoji-jukugo

The lack of examples makes me difficult to understand well the difference between 恥知らず and 厚顔無恥. Both seem to mean "shameless".

For example, can I use both as follows? Are there any differences?

> 脱いだまま公園で散歩する人は**恥知らず**だ。
>   脱いだまま公園で散歩する人は**厚顔無恥**だ。

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either fits in the context, by the way. 恥知らず/厚顔無恥 are strong expressions, usually referring to something that you should be ashamed of as an ethical human being. In other words, it's typically a "how dare you" / "Shame on you!" thing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

「恥知{はじし}らず」 is an originally Japanese word (大和言葉{やまとことば}) as you could tell, I hope, from its reading/pronunciation.  (***Please do not be fooled by the use of kanji (恥 & 知).  The kanji were just "assigned" to the word later on.  Japanese was only a spoken language before we encountered the Chinese and started learning the kanji and created the kana.***)

「厚顔無恥{こうがんむち}」 is, of course, a straight-up Sino-loanword.

Just like the million other Yamato-Sino word pairs, there is little to no difference in the basic meaning.

The difference that does exist is that the Sino counterpart tends to sound ***more formal, more academic, less intuitive***, etc. than the Yamato counterpart, which is why Japanese kids generally learn the Yamato words first.

Finally, the general differences between Yamato words and Sino-loanwords are ***strikingly*** similar, IMHO, to those between English-origin words and "big" Latin loanwords used in English - begin vs. commence, worker vs. employee, put out vs. extinguish, go down vs. descend, etc.

Comment: +1 for calling out the similarity in Sinic loanwords in Japanese and Latinate loanwords in English.  For the amusement of language geeks: there was a short piece written in the late 80s by sci-fi author Poul Anderson, an essay on atomic theory, where he doesn't use any Latinate or Greek-derived terms, using instead only Germanic roots.  The title is [_"Uncleftish Beholding"_](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/cross_fac/complexity/people/students/dtc/students2011/maitland/fun/), the Germanic cognates for _"Atomic Theory"_.  A fun read..  @l'électeur, do you know of any similar 大和言葉だけ modern writings?

Answer (score 5):

These two are basically same meaning,so either one is fine in this situation.
To be exact, for me, 厚顔無恥 sounds a bit stronger than 恥知らず, but Japanese don't care the differences so much.