# What is the difference, in usage, between native Japanese words and their Chinese derived counterparts?

Tags: word-choice

I found some verbs that have Chinese derived counterparts. For example:

- 選ぶー選択する
- 死ぬー死亡する
- 取るー取得する
- 変えるー変更する
- 諦めるー放棄する

How are these words used differently? Are they interchangeable? I think the Chinese derived ones sound more formal, is that right?

Also, I think this happens with adjectives and nouns too:

- 美しいー綺麗
- 優しいー親切
- 当たり前ー当然
- 国ー国家
- 生き物ー生物

Comment: Possible duplicate of [恥知らず【はじしらず】 versus 厚顔無恥【こうがんむち】](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41802/%e6%81%a5%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-%e3%81%af%e3%81%98%e3%81%97%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-versus-%e5%8e%9a%e9%a1%94%e7%84%a1%e6%81%a5-%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c%e3%82%93%e3%82%80%e3%81%a1)

Comment: This has already been discussed multiple times.

Comment: 優しい and 親切 aren't synonyms though.