# how to say "i'll change the meeting day to tomorrow" in japanese?

Tags: word-choice

is this one「私は明日に会議の日を変更する」correct?

Comment: Did you search for this?  I'm almost certain this has been asked before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [恥知らず【はじしらず】 versus 厚顔無恥【こうがんむち】](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41802/%e6%81%a5%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-%e3%81%af%e3%81%98%e3%81%97%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-versus-%e5%8e%9a%e9%a1%94%e7%84%a1%e6%81%a5-%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c%e3%82%93%e3%82%80%e3%81%a1) (based on closure attempt of this exact duplicate, maybe there is a better candidate)

Comment: my main question is how to say " i'll change the meeting day to tomorrow". Idk why my title was changed. Btw thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Yes, both can be used interchangeably, in the case of your sentence.

### Explanation

変更する means to change something that has been decided, like a plan**

変える means to change something in general*. For example, plans, content, etc.

In the latter half of your sentence:

> ...会議の日を変る

変更する and 変える are interchangeable, because 会議の日 is something that has been decided. This fits both definitions. In practice, many people including myself use both interchangeably when talking about schedule.

### Reference

* **変える**

> １
>   物事を以前と違った状態・内容にする。変化させる。変更する。「姿を―・える」「顔色を―・える」「考えを―・える」「話題を―・える」「戦術を―・える」
>
> from https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/37509/meaning/m0u/

** **変更する**

> ［名］(スル)決められた物事などを変えること。「計画を変更する」
>
> from
>   https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/200264/meaning/m0u/%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4/