# What is the difference between 勝利 and 勝ち?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, wago-and-kango

Both mean "victory" so I would like to know when is it more convenient to use **勝ち**, and when shoud I use **勝利** ?

Is one of them more polite ?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41802/%e6%81%a5%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-%e3%81%af%e3%81%98%e3%81%97%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-versus-%e5%8e%9a%e9%a1%94%e7%84%a1%e6%81%a5-%e3%81%93%e3%81%86%e3%81%8c%e3%82%93%e3%82%80%e3%81%a1

Comment: There are already many similar questions on this site. Please see [tag:wago-and-kango] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that one of the two is originally Japanese and the other has been loaned from Chinese.  We have a million word pairs like that if you did not know it.

「勝{か}ち」 is an originally Japanese word as I hope you could tell from its sounds/reading.

「勝利{しょうり}」 is a Sino-loanword.

The big rule of thumb is that in such word pairs, the Sino-loanword is usually more formal, technical, academic, etc. than the more intuitive original Japanese word.  勝利 vs. 勝ち is no exception.  勝利 sounds more formal than 勝ち.

> Is one of them more polite ?

No, this has nothing to do with politeness.  「勝利」 simply is a "bigger" word than 「勝ち」 just as "profound" is a bigger word than "deep" for English-speakers.